# How to get kernel sources corresponding to a particular Fedora build

Tags: kernel, fedora

I needed to move my kernel (centos 6.3) to 2.6.38. After searching on internet I was able to successfully install 2.6.38.8-35.fc15 from
http://kojipkgs.fedoraproject.org/packages/kernel/2.6.38.8/35.fc15/x86_64/kernel-2.6.38.8-35.fc15.x86_64.rpm

I also need the sources of these kernel.
http://kojipkgs.fedoraproject.org/packages/kernel/2.6.38.8/35.fc15/src/kernel-2.6.38.8-35.fc15.src.rpm. However, it turns out that the rpm has only patches like

input-wacom-add-support-for-lenovo-tablet-id-0xe6.patch
intel-iommu-add-domain-check-in-domain_remove_one_dev_info.patch
intel-iommu-check-for-identity-mapping-candidate-using.patch
intel-iommu-dont-cache-iova-above-32bit.patch
intel-iommu-flush-unmaps-at-domain_exit.patch
intel-iommu-only-unlink-device-domains-from-iommu.patch
intel-iommu-remove-host-bridge-devices-from-identity.patch

So how do I get the kernel sources corresponding to this build. Thanks for any inputs

Comment: better place to ask:  http://unix.stackexchange.com/.  also http://www.fedoraforum.org/

Comment: [**Building a custom kernel**](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Building_a_custom_kernel)

Answer (score 2):

There is very easy way for this is yundownloader, use

```
$yumdownload --source kernel
```

to download the source rpm for kernel package, and them install the rpm, and go to `~/rpmbuild`, run

```
rpmbuild -bp SPECS/kernel.spec
```

the patched source tree will be put into `~/rpmbuild/BUILD`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you should do: Go to http://www.kernel.org to download the kernel sources, unpack them, and then you can apply the patches in the source file downloaded to give you the source for that binary package. http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v2.6/linux-2.6.38.8.tar.xz seems to be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I used to enable the source yum repository like **fedora-source** (the default name), then get the kernel source via command `sudo yum install kernel-3.9.5-301.fc19.src`